# Where IDEA's debug jar is?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I am making game using libGDX. To make output JAR smaller, I put all game resources in "data" folder near jar. While I am developing game, I want to run it for debug/test, so I must put "data" folder near JAR. But I cannot find debug jar. Where is it?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your sentences and be more specific? It is difficult to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the question "Where IDEA's debug jar is" it is probably in a directory called `out` or `build` or `bin` or `target` in your project.

Comment: there is a folder "out", but there are only .class files.

Comment: Have you read and followed the guides at: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle and https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA ? I guess this is the setup you are using right?